# How to merge Identity dbcontext with application context?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-identity

I'm not able to read data from Application Identity Users. I'm beginner, any idea? There is no error while compiling. But I cannot add new task.

I get the error while creating a task https://localhost:44312/usertasks/Create

The issue is on GET method but the user lis is not empty

- Results View    Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable
- [0] {lukas@wp.pl}   UserTaskTest.Models.ApplicationUser
      AccessFailedCount   0   int
      ConcurrencyStamp    "785f9a54-e7f1-4e3b-8bad-55165155d631"  string
      Email   "lukas@wp.pl"   string
      EmailConfirmed  false   bool
      ExecutedUserTasks   null    System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
      Id  "53f416ab-aa1e-465f-9dd4-dc32e11914ae"  string
      LockoutEnabled  true    bool
      LockoutEnd  null    System.DateTimeOffset?
      NormalizedEmail "LUKAS@WP.PL"   string
      NormalizedUserName  "LUKAS@WP.PL"   string
      OwnedUserTasks  null    System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
      PasswordHash    "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEIqkXlzky+4i8BsPl5Z4524B3Dj3u0RZMY2Rf5ch5l22GEMj5m0LsVgeWDAavmVO+g=="  string
      PhoneNumber null    string
      PhoneNumberConfirmed    false   bool
      SecurityStamp   "698529ad-c47c-40f9-bdf3-c4d946cda86a"  string
      TwoFactorEnabled    false   bool
      UserName    "lukas@wp.pl"   string
- [1] {li@wp.pl}  UserTaskTest.Models.ApplicationUser
      AccessFailedCount   0   int
      ConcurrencyStamp    "1a9064e2-3cc9-4794-9198-81423a5d8cd2"  string
      Email   "li@wp.pl"  string
      EmailConfirmed  false   bool
      ExecutedUserTasks   null    System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
      Id  "970839dc-31be-4966-8f06-e664aca3622c"  string
      LockoutEnabled  true    bool
      LockoutEnd  null    System.DateTimeOffset?
      NormalizedEmail "LI@WP.PL"  string
      NormalizedUserName  "LI@WP.PL"  string
      OwnedUserTasks  null    System.Collections.Generic.ICollection
      PasswordHash    "AQAAAAEAACcQAAAAEM2KiwEfRDomBNiWXHmEtvwWEodfZDb8eaSADOGP2ZralzlnBDZEMQIsOvTk1nHMcw=="  string
      PhoneNumber null    string
      PhoneNumberConfirmed    false   bool
      SecurityStamp   "0a829111-88d7-4a8a-b65d-5582cecbe67f"  string
      TwoFactorEnabled    false   bool
      UserName    "li@wp.pl"  string

> System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance
>   of an object.
>   at
>   Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItemsWithValueField()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetListItems()
>   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering.MultiSelectList.GetEnumerator()

```
public class UserTask
{
    [Key]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public int UserTaskID { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("OwnerUserID")]
    public string TaskOwnerId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ExecutorUserID")]
    public string TaskExecutorId { get; set; }

    public virtual ApplicationUser OwnerUserID { get; set; }
    public virtual ApplicationUser ExecutorUserID { get; set; }

}


public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
     public ICollection<UserTask> OwnedUserTasks { get; set; }
     public ICollection<UserTask> ExecutedUserTasks { get; set; }
}

public class ApplicationDbContext : IdentityDbContext<ApplicationUser>
{

    public ApplicationDbContext(DbContextOptions<ApplicationDbContext> options) : base(options)
    {
    }

    public DbSet<UserTask> UserTask { get; set; }


    protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder builder)
    {
       base.OnModelCreating(builder);

       builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
           .HasMany(x => x.OwnedUserTasks)
           .WithOne(x => x.OwnerUserID);

       builder.Entity<ApplicationUser>()
           .HasMany(x => x.ExecutedUserTasks)
           .WithOne(x => x.ExecutorUserID);
    }
}
```

Startup.cs

```
public class Startup
{
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddDbContext<ApplicationDbContext>(options =>
            options.UseSqlServer(Configuration.GetConnectionString("DefaultConnection")));

        services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

        // Add application services.
        services.AddTransient<IEmailSender, EmailSender>();

        services.AddMvc();
    }
}
```

UserTaskControler

```
public class UserTasksController : Controller
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;
    private readonly UserManager<ApplicationUser> _userManager;

    public UserTasksController(ApplicationDbContext context, UserManager<ApplicationUser> userManager)
    {
        _context = context;
        _userManager = userManager;
    }

    public IActionResult Create()
    {
        ViewData["TaskOwnerId"] = new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

        ViewData["TaskExecutorId"] = new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "Name");

        return View();
    }
}
```

and the view

```
@model UserTaskTest.Models.UserTask

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h2>Create</h2>

<h4>UserTask</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="Description" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="Description" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="Description" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="TaskOwnerId" class="control-label"></label>
                 <select asp-for="TaskOwnerId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TaskOwnerId"></select>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
             <!--   <label asp-for="TaskExecutorId" class="control-label"></label>
                <select asp-for="TaskExecutorId" class="form-control" asp-items="ViewBag.TaskExecutorId"></select> -->
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-default" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: You forgot to show in Startup that you actually registered `ApplicationDbContext`. You also forgot to show from where you are getting `context` in your Controller. Also forgot to show where you are actually getting that exception

Comment: I added the code, I get the error while creating a task https://localhost:44312/usertasks/Create  Thanks in advance fro your help

Comment: I have edited your question so that only the most relevant details are shown. Does calling `_usermanager.Users.ToList()` give you any item? I'd guess that the table is empty. You did not say whether this is happening on `GET Create` or `POST Create`

Comment: The issue occur on GET Create but the list is not empty

Comment: - Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.ChangeTracking.LocalView<UserTaskTest.Models.ApplicationUser>
+  Non-Public members  
-  Results View Expanding the Results View will enumerate the IEnumerable 
+  [0] {lukas@wp.pl} UserTaskTest.Models.ApplicationUser
+  [1] {li@wp.pl} UserTaskTest.Models.ApplicationUser

Comment: Does this happen on the Controller or after the `return View();`? If this is happening on the View, please post the `Create` view

Comment: i think it is on the view. I posted the view

Comment: I haven't figured out why it is not working. Could you help ?

Comment: @Lukas, try to debug it and or check stacktrace to get place where null error occurs. I gues that error in this place new SelectList(_userManager.Users.ToList(), "Id", "Name"); your ApplicationUser does not have Name try to change it to Email

Answer (score 1):

_userManager is causing the issue here.  It's assuming because of change tracking and the nature of your `ForeignKeys` that you are trying to alter the `User`.  Attempt to fill your Dropdowns with `_dbContext.Users.ToList()`, while it doesn't show available in the context that is generated, it's an inheritance gift.

Also `Name` in your dropdown will error unless you actually created the property in ApplicationUser, since by default it doesn't exist. https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/dev/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Identity.Stores/IdentityUser.cs

```
public class ApplicationUser : IdentityUser
{
   public string Name {get;set;}  //?? missing?

   public ICollection<UserTask> OwnedUserTasks { get; set; }
   public ICollection<UserTask> ExecutedUserTasks { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Now it is working. Could you tell me how to display the name in index and detail view? Sorry for asking so many questions.

Comment: Could you also see  if it was the missing Name property causing or User Manager, pretty sure now it was the Name Property not existing.  As for displaying properties give me a minute.